# Identity in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

In sql server, i created a table with column id as int with identity, second one is name varchar, i created a proc for inserting and i write to statement that after inserting record i want that inserted record id for that i use @@identity it is working but, strangely @@identity is showing more rows, but in table that much records are not there shwoing less recrords. my proc is

```
     alter proc usp_test123  
      as begin  
        set nocount on;  
           insert into test123 values('sasi')  
          select  @@IDENTITY   
           end
```

Comment: Please re-read you question. It does not make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean that the returned identity could be 10, while there are only 8 rows in the table?

`identity` columns are not guaranteed to be contigous. If rows are deleted, or a transaction doing an insert is rolled back, there will be missing numbers in the series.

As a side note, you should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `@@IDENTITY`. `@@IDENTITY` returns the id of the latest row inserted. If there are triggers on the table that you insert into, you would get the latest row inserted by the trigger. `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` gets the latest identity generated in the same code scope.

Comment: ok thank you for response, Anders, is there any clear explanation